# Edmonds-Karp shortest path vs largest bottleneck

Tags: graphs, network-flow

Depending on where I look, some places (https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2009/notes/19-maxflowalgs.pdf) describe EK algorithm as choosing the `st` path with largest bottleneck value, while others (wikipedia) describe it as the shortest path from $s$ to $t$. I'm not sure if they are the same, and I haven't been able to find a proof demonstrating that they are if it is the case. Why does largest bottleneck value correspond to shortest path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest path and the path with the largest bottleneck are not the same in general.

It is easy to construct a counterexample: pick $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{a,b,c\}$, and $E=\{ (a,b), (a,c), (c,b) \}$ where $(a,b)$ has capacity $1$ while $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ have capacity $2$.
The shortest path between $a$ and $b$ consists of the single edge $(a,b)$. The path between $a$ and $b$ with the largest bottleneck is $\langle a,c,b \rangle$.

Besides, the notes that you linked describe and analyze both variants of the Edmonds-Karp algorithm.